# Flutter Empty Constructing value

Tags: flutter, class, object, dart

When I create an object right now, if that object has missing fields those are set to null. Is it possible to make them non-existent if they are empty? Ex:

```
class Example {
  Example({this.username, this.email, this.fullName});
  String username;
  String email;
  String fullName;
}

Example user = Example(username: "john99", fullName: "John Doe");
// This returns a User(username: "john99", fullName: "John Doe", email: null);
// I would like to have this return the following: User(username: "john99", fullName: "John Doe");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is as close as it gets:

```dart
class Example {
  String username;
  String email;

  Example._(this.username, this.email);

  factory Example({@required String username, @required String email, String fullName}) {
    if (fullName == null) return Example._(username, email);
    return _FullExample(username, email, fullName);
  }
}

class _FullExample extends Example {
  String fullName;

  _FullExample(String username, String email, this.fullName)
    : super._(username, email);
}
```

Does it seem a bit contrived and overly verbose? Good, because it should.

Dart is not Javascript. Objects aren't secretly records that can gain or lose properties dynamically. It is a statically-typed language with clear contracts on what fields a type does and doesn't have. When you declare a field in a Dart class, instances of that class will have that field, whether it contains an instantiated value or `null`. In other words, Dart has no concept of `undefined` as a static value - only as a compile-time or runtime error.

When you have a requirement like "remove an unused field from a class", take a step back and question whether you have a legitimate reason for having such a requirement, or if perhaps you are trying to treat Dart like something it's not. If the latter, then you would be better off switching to something like React Native that *does* use Javascript where stuff like this is idiomatic instead of making the language bend over backward for you just to make you feel more comfortable using development methodologies that were never intended for that language.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to adapt my code in a different way.

Comment: Well, except for Expando objects. :)

Comment: @RandalSchwartz The `Expando` class exists solely for Dart interop with Javascript and HTML DOM representation. Like virtually every other Dart feature originally designed for Javascript interop, it is an extremely niche legacy feature that is extremely abusable and shouldn't be utilized by anyone unless they truly know what they are doing.

Comment: And frankly I wouldn't even call the `Expando` class a language feature so much as a hack. In practice, it is just a fancy `Map` with weak references.

Comment: Yeah, was thinking that's really all it is.  But there's no other way to get weak references.  I also wish there was a way to get GC notifications, but that's not supported by JS, so we probably won't ever get it.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz Yeah, most of my biggest complaints about Dart as a language can be traced back to its roots as a transpilation language for Javascript. If it wasn't for Flutter Web, I would argue Dart would do so much better if the Javascript legacy "features" were officially sunset once and for all.